# Compile C++ .lib files make them DLL for C# enviroment

Tags: c#, c++

I've got plenty of these object file library :
addrstor.exp
authhlp.lib

I would like to have them as a DLL and add into the C# project and try to use the method which involved.

How could I achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

C# is ideally suited to calling in to "C" functions. One way is to create an C adapter to the C++ functionality:

Step 1: Expose a C function from the DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int someMethod(int paramA);
```

Step 2: Import in to C#

```
[DllImport("your.dll", EntryPoint="someMethod")]
public static extern UInt32 NiceNameFunc(UInt32 paramA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want calling native DLL (C++/libs) called from managed (C#) code:

- make sure your functions are exported form the DLL
- use whatever favorite linker to link Libs to DLL.
- create C# class with methods annotated with [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
- make sure your C# project is set for same bitness (x86/x64) as native DLL

If you want compile C++ Libs to managed DLL (assembly) - you can't do that. You may be able to use managed C++ to compile sources to a assembly.